scikit-learn CCA: x_loadings_x attribute
I'm doing a canonical correlation analysis using scikit-learn's CCA. After doing the usual steps and calling ca.x_loadings_, I see that I get values bigger than 1. How I intepret the explanation of what the attribute x_loadings_ should represent however, this contradicts with the loading being a correlation. What does the attribute x_loadings_ represent precisely?
n_comp = 3 #choose number of canonical variates pairs, maximum is min of dimensions of X and Y
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA

# instantiate cca object and fit
ca = CCA(n_components=n_comp)
ca.fit(x_standardized, y_standardized)
X_c, Y_c = ca.transform(x_standardized, y_standardized) #transform our datasests to obtain canonical variates

print(ca.x_loadings_)
print(ca.y_loadings_)


cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78725061/10495893
